# XPath with multiple contains on different elements

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, contains

Is it possible to have `XPath` expression with multiple contains of different element values?

**XML**

```
<data>
   <person>
      <firstname>Kerry</firstname>
      <lastname>Packer</lastname>
      <address>Crown</address>
   <person>
   <person>
      <firstname>Kerry</firstname>
      <lastname>Murdoch</lastname>
      <address>California</address>
   <person>
<data>
```

**PHP**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$elements = $xml->xpath("(//person)[firstname[contains(., 'Kerr')]] and [lastname[contains(., 'och')]]");
```

Currently above `XPath` expression is flagged as invalid. However if I use it with one element,

```
$xml->xpath("(//person)[firstname[contains(., 'Kerr')]]");
```

then it works fine.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You simply want

```
//person[contains(firstname, 'Kerr') and contains(lastname, 'och')]
```

Comment: We can also use an "or" clause in the search.