# Xpath selector doesn't filter out class when iterating over selector list

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am scraping this site: https://www.oddsportal.com/darts/europe/european-championship/results/

this site uses javascript to **render table data**, hence I have used **scrapy-splash** plugin in a docker container.

I want to filter out all rows with class 'dark center' while iterating over the selector list 'tableRows'. **however when iterating it appears the xpath selector queries the entire SelectorList opposed to each item at each iteration**

```
tableRows = response.xpath('//table[contains(@id, "tournamentTable")]/tbody/tr')

    for row in tableRows:
        print(row)
        if row.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "dark center")]') is not None:
            print(True)
```

My output:

```
<Selector xpath='//table[contains(@id, "tournamentTable")]/tbody/tr' data='<tr class="dark center" xtid="39903"><th'>
True
<Selector xpath='//table[contains(@id, "tournamentTable")]/tbody/tr' data='<tr class="center nob-border"><th class='>
True
```

Why is the class 'center nob-border' returning True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bit wrong XPath. Take a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath)
You've missed dot in second XPath expression. In short:

```
# Search document root for mentioned node.
row.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "dark center")]')

# In fact it's the same as
response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "dark center")]')

# Search element root for mentioned node(what you're really need) is
row.xpath('./*[contains(@class, "dark center")]')
# or .//*[contains(@class, "dark center")] possibly, depending on DOM structure
```

---

**Large update here..**
Ahaha... in fact in was really dumb of me.
Well... You had two mistakes in your code actually. First one was Xpath expression that I've mentioned. And the second one is the comparison operator.

```
row.xpath('any XPath here') is not None
```

Will always return True. Since the function return type is a list, it can be empty but it never can be NoneType. So it goes. I've also improved the Xpath selector...
Finally, a totally accurate code you need is:

```
tableRows = response.xpath('//table[contains(@id, "tournamentTable")]/tbody/tr')

for row in tableRows:
    print(row)
    if row.xpath('./self::tr[contains(@class, "dark center")]'):
        print(True)
```

Comment: same result for both suggestions. I am perplexed

Comment: how is ```row.xp...``` and response.xp...``` the same? when ```row.xp...``` is only one item in a selector list?

Comment: And by the way. Do you aware of that you are trying to get js rendered data?
I mean there's no such data in the document body at all before javascript has been rendered.

Comment: try `scrapy view https://www.oddsportal.com/darts/europe/european-championship/results/` so see which exactly data scrapy can operate.

Comment: Yeah I am using scrapy-splash plugin

Comment: You are leading me in the right direction however in regards to searching the root element, I just need a index in my query somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that there is no `dark center` in the downloaded page. Those classes are created after the page load, by some javascript code. If you search for them  in `View Page Source` you yon't find them.

However, the data you want is in another url. Something like: `https://www.oddsportal.com/ajax-sport-country-tournament-archive/14/rwHQ6U5F/X0/1/0/1/?_=1563816992686`

```
$ curl -s https://www.oddsportal.com/ajax-sport-country-tournament-archive/14/rwHQ6U5F/X0/1/0/1/\?_\=1563816992686 | cut -c -500

-|-{"s":1,"d":{"html":"<table class=\" table-main\" id=\"tournamentTable
\"><colgroup><col width=\"50\" \/><col width=\"*\" \/><col width=\"50\" 
\/><col width=\"50\" \/><col width=\"50\" \/><col width=\"50\" \/><col width=\"50\" \/><\/colgroup><tbody><tr class=\"dark center\" xtid=\"39903\"
><th class=\"first2 tl\" colspan=\"7\"><a class=\"bfl sicona s14\" href=\"
\/darts\/\">Darts<\/a><span class=\"bflp\">\u00bb<\/span><a class=\"bfl\"
href=\"\/darts\/europe\/\"><span class=\"ficon f-6\">&nbsp;<\/
```

You will have to find out how to proper assemble that url. All I know is that the last parameter is a timestamp. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks sorry I should have mentioned I am running splash on a docker container to render the javascipt for scrapy

Answer (score 0):

If you want all elements that have class 'dark center' you could use:

```
//tr[@class="dark center"]
```

> Why is the class 'center nob-border' returning True?

The result is true because you are searching for all tr tags without specifying a class or id and **contains** does not work with multiple keywords. It is using  and **or** statement between them.

Reference:
[XPath with multiple contains on different elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547410/xpath-with-multiple-contains-on-different-elements)

Comment: this selector returns the same result,i'm perfoming the xpath selector on one  in the selector list not the entire table. hence, the row variable.

Answer (score 0):

Correct xpath for your requirement would be `//table[contains(@id, "tournamentTable")]//tr[@class='dark center']`

With this xpath you will search in the table with id `tournamentTable` and rows with class `dard center`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting them:

```
tableRows = response.xpath('//table[contains(@id, "tournamentTable")]/tbody/tr').getall()
    for row in tableRows:
        print(row)
        if row.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "dark center")]').get() is not None:
            print(True)
```

Comment: same result. I am perplexed