# XPath with multiple contains on similar elements

Tags: html, xpath

My question looks similar to [XPath with multiple contains on different elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547410/xpath-with-multiple-contains-on-different-elements), but i try solution and cant get correct result. May be I do some wrong.
So i have table:

```html
<div id="openTrades" style="display: block"><table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>95326</td>
    <td>BRENT_OIL</td>
    <td>2019-10-29 11:51:14</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>60.67</td>
    <td>buy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>95325</td>
    <td>SILVER</td>
    <td>2019-10-29 10:38:26</td>
    <td>1</td><td>20</td>
    <td>17.545</td>
    <td>sell</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</div>
```

So i try get all cells with date "2019-10-29" and "sell" status.
I try to use x-path:

```
'//*[@id="openTrades"]//tr[contains(td,"buy") and contains(td,"2019-10-29")]'
```

and

```
'//*[@id="openTrades"]/table/tbody//tr/*[contains(td,"sell") and contains(td,"2019-10-29")]'
```

i cant get no one element.

**Also for**

```
'//*[@id="openTrades"]/table/tbody//tr/*[self::td[contains(.,"sell")] or self::td[contains(.,"2019-10-29")]]'
```

i get 58 elements - 57 with contains(.,"2019-10-29") and 1 with contains(.,"sell")
but when i use

```
'//*[@id="openTrades"]/table/tbody//tr/*[self::td[contains(.,"sell")] and self::td[contains(.,"2019-10-29")]]'
```

i cant get no one.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself:

```
'//*[@id="openTrades"]//td[contains(.,"2019-10-29")]/../td[contains(.,"sell")]'
```

other way aply to 'tr':

```
'//tr[contains(.,"2019-10-29") and contains(.,"sell") ]'
```

you can add more then two value

Comment: Your expression only selects the word `sell`; is that the target or is it the whole `tr` which includes the date and `sell`, as well as `SILVER` etc.?

Comment: yes, in my case I need date and 'sell' pair combination for one tr, but no ned select tr - just count

Comment: Then you probably have to add `count()` around your expression.