# xpath leads to 2 elements how can I make it more specific?

Tags: xpath

Source is the obstacle course: https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/23292

The Xpath I try is:

```
//*[contains(text(),'John')]
```

But that leads to 2 elements

How can I improve the Xpath so It can find the TR with John Doe?

Comment: found something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621663/xpath-with-multiple-contains-on-similar-elements

Answer (score 1):

```
//tr[contains(.,"John") and contains(.,"Doe") ]
```

Comment: This is a very low quality answer, this possibly shoulda been comment. try to include an explanation why it worked for you.

Comment: It's a little hard to imagine what part of this answer the OP won't understand. But then, it's a little hard to understand why they had to ask the question in the first place.